# smoke-free buildings -> smoke-full outdoor

Tags: health

Most countries have smoke-free workplace, this is really really the minimum acceptable in my opinion, but even with that, I find it very hard to enter or leave a building without entering those toxic clouds.

People smoking often doesn't consider the wind direction, and it even seems they are less in danger than the smoke stream spreading with wind to other people

**Problem**: in my country (France) ashtrays are systematically in front of doors, and people are smoking directly there, I've contacted the company renting the offices, explaining the advantage of putting ashtrays farther, no replies yet, they surely don't care, without any more incentive or law
**Question**: What could you suggest?

Below are sources pretty scary concerning Environmental Tobacco Smoke, that caused me this fumiphobia, that should normally make stop any smoker instantly and permanently. I'm really keeping breath, optimizing my way for not taking even 0.1% of ETS (you will think it' excessive, but there is no smoke exposure threshold known at this time, any theshold might cause harm):

-[Is PM2.5 From Air Pollution The Same As From Smoking?](http://www.myhealthbeijing.com/pollution/is-pm2-5-from-air-pollution-the-same-as-from-smoking/)
-[Proposed Identification of
Environmental Tobacco Smoke as a
Toxic Air Contaminant](http://ash.org/CAEPAProposal.pdf)
-[Particulate matter from tobacco versus diesel car exhaust](http://tobaccocontrol.bmj.com/content/13/3/219.full.pdf+html?ijkey=330b5aea15a8e36fcc2f4208cf99da58d84150f3)
-[Chemistry and Toxicology of Cigarette Smoke and Biomarkers of Exposure and Harm](http://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/books/NBK53014/)

Comment: I think you forgot to actually ask a question.

Comment: Asking broadly for general advice or for people's attitude/opinion is off-topic. Do you have a specific problem you are trying to solve? If so, could you [edit] your question to describe what your problem is and how you would like to solve it?

Comment: @Jim there, sorry I don't mean to put a polemic question, does it sound as such? There are advanced countries on these topics, there others really far, and I hope to make minds change, this is not a normal situation to breath smoke, I hope people thinking so change their mind

Comment: You seem to be asking a much broader question than one specifically about the workplace.  It sounds like you want to move ashtrays everywhere (you mentioned supermarkets, for example).  I suggest focusing this on the problem you face *at your workplace*.  I also don't think we need to see the anti-smoking argument; this isn't a health site.  Your problem is that you are uncomfortable with the smoke clouds (I'm with you there) and you want to be able to get to and from your workplace unmolested by it, right?

Comment: @MonicaCellio thanks yes, it's a stress that I live personally very strongly, unfortunately it's a broader sociological issue so I understand why the topic is almost closed. There is no easy solution apart from moving away, in my country the ground is covered by butts, unlike other countries where people are responsible

Answer (score 4):

At least in America, a "smoke free workplace" actually includes some fixed distance from doorways. If your coworkers are violating that, then talk to your manager or HR. They can then do the "please respect the non-smokers and obey the law" speech.

If the smokers are within their rights, then suck it up and focus on doing your job. Making people not smoke is something you're free to advocate for in your non-working hours.

Comment: Ok, another reason to move to USA or UK (they do it also I think), also smokers feel quickly angry about it whereas they are responsible